# how to use check constraint in postgresql for string

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

i am new to postgres

how to create table with check constraint for column name say **polluted** which only have to accept 'yes' or 'no' values on insert.

for other values it should promote error message

My table name is **vehicles**

Comment: my table name is vehicles

Comment: Why don't you use a `boolean` type? That would be a much better choice for a yes/no flag

Comment: but i want for future purpose for other requirements

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use an `in` condition.

```
create table vehicles
(
  id integer primary key, 
  polluted text not null check (polluted in ('yes', 'no'))
);
```

Comment: your query working fine and also how to write constraint error message if other value is inserted